# Trasfer MySql from Windows to ubuntu

Tags: mysql, windows, ubuntu, migration

I am using wamp in windows 7. Due to some reason my os is corrupted but still i have ubuntu in my pc and wamp was in another drive.

Now I can get source of my project but how to get database from mysql. I think I can use .frm and other files that can be restore in ubuntu.

Anyone could you please explain how can I restore my wamp/mysql data to ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you should be able to copy your .frm, .myd, and myi from your windows box to your linux box.  Assuming you used something like XAMPP, the files are stored in \mysql\data

These would need to be copied to /var/lib/mysql

You might need to recreate your user(s) though.

Comment: yeah i found out something somethin same. I will try and let you know :) thx for your suggestion.